# Need help positioning two columns in row

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, positioning

I'm reworking my portfolio website using bootstrap 4. Everything seems to be going fine until I got to my project showcase.

I have a row that should have two columns. One column with a pic and the second column with the description. But for some reason the columns are stacking vertically not horizontally and I can't figure out why it's doing that.

I deleted sections above the row to see if that's the issue and the columns still stack. I rewrote the code to a simple row with simple columns and still didn't fix the problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
<title>Jessica perkins Porfolio Page</title>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset ="60">
    <!--Header and Nav-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="header-container">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"><span class="fa fa-home fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
              </div>

              <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 1px;">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                      <li class="about-nav"><a href="#about-section" class="nav-link" ><i class="fa fa-id-card-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>About<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                      <li class="skills-nav"><a href="#skills-section" class="nav-link"><i class="far fa window-maximize" aria-hidden="true"></i>Skills</a></li>
                      <li class="work-nav"><a href="#work-section" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-code" aria-hidden="true"></i>Work</a></li>
                      <li class="contact-nav"><a href="#contact-section" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>Contact</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <div class="bgimg-1">
          <div class="header-content" id="home">
              <div data-aos="fade-down">
                <h1 class="name1">Jessica Perkins</h1>
              </div>
              <div data-aos="fade-up">
                <p class="s-name">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</p>
              </div>

              <hr>
  <!--Icons-->
              <div class="media">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="https://github.com/jnperk1234" target="_blank" class="github-link"><i
                        class="fab fa-github-alt fa-3x"></i></a> </li>
                  <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/jessica-perkins0304/" target="_blank" class="linkedin-link"><i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-3x"></a></i>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/jessica.perkins.7965" target="_blank" class="facebook-link"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-3x"></a></i></li>
                  <li><a href="https://www.deviantart.com/icysisdee" target="_blank" class="deviantart-link"><i
                        class="fab fa-deviantart fa-3x"></a></i></li>
                  <li> <a href="mailto:jnpdesignnarts@gmail.com"><i class="email-link fa fa-envelope-o"
                        aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="down">
            <a class="next-page" href="#about-section"><i class="animated pulse infinite fa fa-chevron-circle-down fa-2x"
                aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
          </div>
      </header>
      <br>
    </div>

<!--AboutMe-->
<div class="container" id="about-section">
  <h1>Hi! My is Jessica!</h1>
  <br>
  <h2>I am <span class="typed"></span></h2>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="profile-pic">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <p class="about me">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
          labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
          aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
          eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
          mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="bgimg-2"></div>
<!--Skills-->
<section class="skill- section py-5">
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Skill Overview</h1>
    <h3>What I can do</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
    aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
    occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>

    <div class="skills-blocks mx-auto pt-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 mb-5 mb-lg-0">
           <section class="skill-block title-border">
            <button type="button" class="btn-circle btn-xl"><i class="fas fa-file-code"></i></button>
            <h2 class="text-title-center text-title-text-h2">Test</h2>
            <hr>
            <ul class="skills-list list-unstyled text-secondary">
              <li class="mb-2"><i class="fas fa-check mr-2 text-primary"></i>React</li>
              <li class="mb-2"><i class="fas fa-check mr-2 text-primary"></i>Javascript</li>
              <li class="mb-2"><i class="fas fa-check mr-2 text-primary"></i>Node.js</li>
              <li class="mb-2"><i class="fas fa-check mr-2 text-primary"></i>HTML/CSS/SASS/LESS</li>
            </ul>
          </section>
        </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 mb-5 mb-lg-0">
              <section class="skill-block title-border">
                <button type="button" class="btn-circle btn-xl"><i class="fas fa-file-code"></i></button>
                <h2 class="text-title-center text-title-text-h2">Test</h2>
                <hr>
                <ul class="skills-list list-unstyled text-secondary">
                  <li class="mb-2"><i class="fas fa-check mr-2 text-primary"></i>React</li>
                  <li class="mb-2"><i class="fas fa-check mr-2 text-primary"></i>Javascript</li>
                  <li class="mb-2"><i class="fas fa-check mr-2 text-primary"></i>Node.js</li>
                  <li class="mb-2"><i class="fas fa-check mr-2 text-primary"></i>HTML/CSS/SASS/LESS</li>
                </ul>
              </section>
            </div>
              <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 mb-5 mb-lg-0">
                <section class="skill-block title-border">
                  <button type="button" class="btn-circle btn-xl"><i class="fas fa-file-code"></i></button>
                  <h2 class="text-title-center text-title-text-h2">Test</h2>
                  <hr>
                  <ul class="skills-list list-unstyled text-secondary">
                    <li class="mb-2"><i class="fas fa-check mr-2 text-primary"></i>React</li>
                    <li class="mb-2"><i class="fas fa-check mr-2 text-primary"></i>Javascript</li>
                    <li class="mb-2"><i class="fas fa-check mr-2 text-primary"></i>Node.js</li>
                    <li class="mb-2"><i class="fas fa-check mr-2 text-primary"></i>HTML/CSS/SASS/LESS</li>
                  </ul>
                </section>
              </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



<!-- <div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      Test
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      Test
    </div>
  </div> -->

</div>
<div class="container container-work">
  <div id="work-section">
    <h2 class="work-header">My Projects</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="work-sample">
          <div class="work-img col-sm-6 col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-0">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500">
          </div>
          <div class="work-info col-sm-6 col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-0">
            <h4>Project 1</h4>
            <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
              incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
              aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
              consequat. Duis
              aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
              Excepteur sint
              occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Just need the columns to align horizontally
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```php
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="work-header">My Projects</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/500"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <h4>Project 1</h4>
      <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute
        irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your classes are wrong. It should be container>row>col

Comment: @JessicaPerkins No problem! Did that solve your issue?

Comment: Yes! I also realize I had a bunch of typos and the wrong version of bootstrap